# how to display the contents of file in multi-line textbox in readable format and in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using FileUpload Control to upload the files in FileUpload.aspx page, now i wants to display the contents of file in different page say -filecontents.aspx.
For that i am using StreamReader and even getting the contents but in encoded format(not in readable format).

How to get the contents of uploaded file in readable format.

Here is my code:

```
public string ShowContent(string path)
    {
        string savePath = @"D:\CloudStorageSecurity\CloudStorageSecurity\CloudServer1\";
        string strInput = "";
        string GetStream = "";

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.Unicode);
            strInput = sr.ReadLine();
            while (strInput != null)
            {
                GetStream += strInput;
                strInput = sr.ReadLine();
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("file does not exist!");
        }
        txtFileCOntents.Text = GetStream;
    }
```

Comment: did you try UTF8 for encoding?

Comment: Yes tried, but getting same result

Comment: i am doing that , i n code i didnt show it,, Here it goes like this,,string savePath = @"D:\CloudStorageSecurity\CloudStorageSecurity\CloudServer1\Resume.Docx";

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the `path` is a valid path and points to a readable file format (txt,html,rtf ...):

```
public string ShowContent(string path)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            using(var sr = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                 result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                 sr.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("file does not exist!");
        }
        txtFileCOntents.Text = result ;
    }
```

while you have `result`, you could do any thing with that.
If you want to read line by line:

```
public string ShowContent(string path)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        var tmpLine = string.Empty;
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            using(var sr = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                 while((tmpLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                 {
                     result += tmpLine + "\n\r";
                 }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("file does not exist!");
        }
        txtFileCOntents.Text = result ;
    }
```

Comment: what's the extension of your file?

Comment: I am getting decoded format contents like:  PK�����!��h"�������[Content_Types].xml �(�������������������������������������������������...How to do with this ????

Comment: try to open your file in a simple text editor, like notepad or notepad++. if you get the same things, you have to change the encoding of your file before save it.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on what kind of file you are trying to "read".

I see in the comment you are trying to parse a docx format. You can get the readable content via OpenXML. I guess this link should help you get started.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSOpenXmlGetPlainText-554918c3